# Does the bremsstrahlung radiation size depends on the size of the accelerator?

Tags: electromagnetism, radiation

According to [this,](https://apps.dtic.mil/dtic/tr/fulltext/u2/a351472.pdf) HERMES III, a 16 terawatt pulsed power accelerator at Sandia National Labs, which fired electron beams with peak energy at 22 MeV and 730 ka current that later converted into Bremsstrahlung radiation is used to irradiate very large area and very large test objects such as military tanks to simulate nuclear explosion gamma ray radiation effects on whole weapon systems and large armoured vehicles.

What determined the size of the Bremsstrahlung radiation fields? Is it simply the size of the accelerator or the voltage and current regardless the size of the accelerator?

Comment: First, this is a physics question. Second, Bremsstrahlung is "braking" radiation, caused by the change of speed of a charged particle. Here, when the electrons are stopped by the target, they produce electromagnetic radiation up to 22 Mev gamma rays. Third, the size is virtually unlimited. How far does a flashlight beam go? It just gets weaker at distance.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik thanks for the response. I asked the same "What determined the size of gamma ray fields?" at the physics section and anna v told me it is all engineering. But it's ok as you've responded to the question. Then, if the size is unlimited, even a compact laser system in the petawatt level (for example, this https://iopscience.iop.org/article/10.1088/1367-2630/aad71a) can generate very large area gamma ray fields too like HERMES III if the voltage and current is high enough. Correct?

Comment: Again, "area" is meaningful only if you include *strength*, or *intensity*, of the radiation. A candle flame covers an indefinite area; For example, the Webb Telescope could spot a candle burning (in a dome with oxygen;-) on a moon of Jupiter, https://earthsky.org/space/james-webb-space-telescope-gets-its-first-instrument . The candle light covers a large area. It's not very intense, though, by the time it reaches Earth.

Comment: @DrMoishePippik right. So I just found some articles talking about small area accelerators. According to https://ieeexplore.ieee.org/document/1003878?reload=true&arnumber=1003878 a small diameter anode seems essential so the rays only affect small areas. While https://rb.gy/eufrsn said a small focal spot is needed. If you see HERMES III diode, it is very large. So I think that explains why the bremsstrahlung fields are so large. If you're free, you can see the isodose contours of HERMES III in the first link in my OP at page 39 and 40 and the bremsstrahlung rays are very large.